# How do I make toggle() work for this element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an `<input>` with type `Search` and class as `SearchBox`. I want this `input` to toggle when I click an `img` of class `Search`. I've connected my html page to jQuery 1.11.1 available from `ajax.googleapis.com` and this is my .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Search").click(function () {
        $("input.SearchBox").toggle();
    });
});
```

I've hidden the `SearchBox` using CSS, like this:

```
.SearchBox {
display: none;
}
```

But it does not work. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.
the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Connet, connect, consultation online">
        <meta name="description" content="Website of Connet.">
        <meta name="author" content="Connet Developement Team">
        <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-US">
        <title> Connet. Connect. Through the internet. </title>
        <link rel="favicon" href="favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/page_files/css/Main.style.css" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="/page_files/js/Default.interactivity.js"></script>
        <script src="/page_files/js/Default.proccessing.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="/page_files/js/jQuery3.0.0.js"></script>-->
        <script src="/page_files/data/Default.data.js" ></script>
        <script id="roughScript">
        </script>
        <noscript>
            We're sorry, but looks like we can't
            access our scripts. Refreshing might fix it.
            Check yor internet connection. If it's our
            fault we'll usually have something about it 
            in our blogs. Contact us if problem persists.
        </noscript>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
  <body>
        <div class="Wrapper">
            <nav>
                <img src="bf" alt="tbf"/>
                <ul class="NavClass">
                    <li>
                        <a class="NavLink" onclick="location.reload();">
                            <img class="NavImg" src="/page_files/media/home-icon.png" alt="Home" />    
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="NavLink" onclick="open('Contact.html');">
                            <img class="NavImg" src="/page_files/media/contact-icon.png" alt="Contact" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="NavLink" onclick="open('Careers.html');">
                            <img class="NavImg" src="/page_files/media/careers-icon.png" alt="Careers" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="NavLink" onclick="open('Conroot.html');">
                            <img class="NavImg" src="/page_files/media/consult-icon.png" alt="Enter Consulation" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="NavLink" onclick="open('Loginpage.html');">
                            <img class="NavImg" src="/page_files/media/myspace-icon.png" alt="Login" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="Search" src="/page_files/media/search-icon.png" alt="Search" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input class="SearchBox" type="search" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <header>
            </header>

            <div class="Sections">
                <section class="TopSec">
                </section>
                <section class="MidSec">
                </section>
                <section class="LowSec">
                </section>
                <section class="SignIn">
                </section>
            </div>

            <footer>
            </footer>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And please do ask me for any extra information if needed.

Comment: Your class names don't match. Show your html as well.

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/mbp5109z/)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but not for me. I have the html file's gist over [here](https://gist.github.com/aravind-suresh-vs/713503b4596fbfe2d35c2974198259b9)

Comment: @AravindSuresh: Well, as Schlaus said, it belongs in your question.

Comment: Are you including your JS file with the above code *before jQuery reference*? Check your console.

Comment: I see nothing wrong when I extracted all the code into a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tnz6cus/). Perhaps as @ShaunakD mentioned, something is wrong with your other included JavaScript, or jQuery's `$` is being overwritten. One suggestion is to try using `jQuery` instead of `$` in your JavaScript code.